# Query multiple rows that leads to one row in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a noob at making mySQL queries so I couldn't get my work done. I hope you guys know the answer to my question.

I want to make options to my products. Like if you have a black t-shirt, with a tanktop model and diamonds on it. You must have the black t-shirt tanktop model and diamonds row. I want to make it like this:

```
table: product_option
--------------------------------
product_option_id   name    product_combination_id
1                   Black   1
2                   Diamond 1
3                   Tanktop 1
4                   Option  2
5                   Option  2

table: product_combination
--------------------------------
product_combination_id   name                         
1                        Black tanktop with diamonds
```

So my question is. Is it possible to query the product_options and get an product_combination row out of it?

I hope you guys know the answer to my question! Thank you for your time :)

### EDIT:

I think my question was too general and I want to ask it more specific.

Let's say. I have a shop with clothes. I have a product (let's say an T-shirt). And there are a couple of options to choose from.

Like this:

```
Color:
- Black
- Red
- Orange

Size
- Large
- Xtra Large
- Medium
- Small

Accessoire:
- Diamonds
- Printed
- Swarovski
```

Let's say I want to buy the Black / Xtra Large T-shirt with Diamonds on it. Then the `product_combination` must be Black/Large/Diamonds Row. I think I need an Foreign table with a Many to Many relation. Like product_combination_option table with the columns:

```
 product_combination_option
 - product_combination_option_id
 - product_combination_id
 - product_option_id
```

But then again. How can I query when someone chooses Black / Xtra Large with Diamonds and find which `product_combination` it is.

I hope I'm a bit clearer now. Sorry that I updated my question so late! I appreciate all your answers very much!

Comment: How are you trying to query the database? With a given option name or option id? If you go by name, it likely won't end up being unique, since the way the table is designed now each name has a one-to-one association with a combination.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is joining your tables, so that you can pick up a combination based on the product you have.
So, for that, a query can be

```
Select * 
from product_option inner join product_combination
using(product_combination_id);
```

This joins the 2 tables. so you can replace the * with the list of attributes you want to display/fetch.

Comment: I'm sorry. That's not what I'm looking for. I want to make an query that get's query the 'product_option' table and delivers me an 'product_combination'

Comment: Have you tried concatenating the values which are fetched by the product attribute combinations, and then fetching from the combination table ? However, what I think, it will be a lot of work for you to enter that many combinations into that table. Why not just concatenate and fetch that concatenated combination, instead of making a new table ? Do tell me if I understand your question this time.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to pass a list of options to the query and get a list of matching `product_combination` entries, then here's one way:

```
SELECT *
FROM product_combination
WHERE product_combination_id IN (
  SELECT product_combination
  FROM product_option
  WHERE name IN ('option1', 'option2', 'option3')
  GROUP BY product_combination
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
);
```

The subquery returns a set of `product_combination` values that have all three options requested. The `COUNT(*) = 3` condition assumes that a single `product_combination` value cannot have duplicate `name` values associated with it. (Which is only natural, but in case your table doesn't have the corresponding restriction, you could replace `COUNT(*)` with `COUNT(DISTINCT name)` to make sure a group being returned contains all three options specified and not just three rows of which some contain identical options.)

Of course, if the number of options queried isn't fixed, you'll need to build the query dynamically because of the IN predicate, because it is not parametrisable (in terms of the number of items). However, you could try using a temporary rowset instead of a hardcoded list. The table would be populated before running the query in question, which in this case would be modified to this effect:

```
SELECT *
FROM product_combination
WHERE product_combination_id IN (
  SELECT product_combination
  FROM product_option
  WHERE name IN (SELECT option_name FROM requested_options)
  GROUP BY product_combination
  HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM requested_options)
);
```

In the above query, `requested_options` is the name of the temporary storage (possibly a temporary table, but I'm not sure if MySQL allows you to access one that was created and  and populated beforehand in a different query), and `option_name` is its column containing the options being requested.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I really appreciate it. The 'product_option' is a table with all the options. The number of options is not fixed. I think I need an foreign table like product_combination_option. Where I put all the combinations possible with the options that are in product_option. In my question i edited my question to be more specific. I hope you can understand that I'm a bit bad in english. And therefore it's hard to get my questions right. I hope you can understand now what I try to accomplish!

Comment: Ah, so it now appears that you've got another problem to solve, that of the schema design (or *re*-design, perhaps). Please don't get me wrong but I think your original problem, about a query, becomes moot at this point, since it is now unclear what exactly (which tables and which columns thereof) is going to be queried. You should get first things first: get a clear idea about how your data will be stored *before* trying to solve the problem(s) of how to query them. If you need help with that, please post a new question. I'm sure there are many people here with great suggestions about that.